# Output vector for YOLO and sliding window algorithms

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

As I understand in YOLO algorithm we divide inuput image into a grid, for example 19x19 and we have to have output vector (pc, bx, by, bh bw, c) for each cell. Then we can train our network. And my question is: why we give to network XML file with only one bounding box, labels etc. (if only one object is on image) instead of give 19*19=361 ones? Does implementation of network divide image and create vector for each cell automatically? (How it do that?)

The same question is for sliding window algorithm. Why we give to network only one vector with label and bounding box instead of giving vector for each sliding window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let' say that the output of YOLO is composed of 19 by 19 grid cells, and each grid cell has some depth. Each grid cell can detect some bounding boxes, whose maximum number depends on the configuration of the model. For example, if one grid cell can detect up to 5 bounding boxes, the model can detect 19x19x5 = 1805 bounding boxes in total.

Since this number is too large, we train the model such that **only the grid cell that contains the center of the bounding box within it** predicts a bounding box with high confidence. When we train the model, we first figure out where the center of the true bounding box falls, and train the model such that the grid cell containing the center will predict a bounding box similar to the truth one with high probability, and such that other grid cells will predict bounding boxes with as lower probability as possible (when the probability is lower than a threshold, this prediction is discarded).

The image below shows a grid cell containing the box center when the output has 13 by 13 grid cells.

[image]

This is the same when there are more than one object in the training images. If there are two object in a training image, we update the two grid cells that contain the centers of the true two boxes such that they produce bounding boxes with high probability.